# Parsing a log file in Java to display only messages

Tags: java, parsing, logging

I'm having a hard time with getting this to work. I have a very large .log file that I need read into the code, I need to parse and format the code, and then export it to a text document containing the right information in the right order. Here is my code so far:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class chatLogParse {
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

String path = "sampleData.log";
FileInputStream inputStream = null;
Scanner input = null;
String filename;
// Connecting to a file with a buffer
        PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(
                              new BufferedWriter(
                              new FileWriter("ChatOutput.txt")));

try {inputStream = new FileInputStream(path);
input = new Scanner(inputStream, "UTF-8");
while (input.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println(line);
}
// note that Scanner suppresses exceptions
if (input.ioException() != null) {
    throw input.ioException();
}
} finally {
if (inputStream != null) {
    inputStream.close();
}
if (input != null) {
    input.close();
    }
   }
  }
 }
```

Here is a snippet of the log file:

```
08:25:26.668 [D] [T:000FF4] [F:LANTALK2C] <CMD>LANMSG</CMD>
<MBXID>1124</MBXID><MBXTO>5760</MBXTO><SUBTEXT>LanTalk</SUBTEXT><MOBILEADDR>
</MOBILEADDR><LAP>0</LAP><SMS>0</SMS><MSGTEXT>but didn't give me the info I 
needed</MSGTEXT>
08:25:26.672 [+] [T:000FF4] [S:1:1:1124:5607:5] LANMSG [0/2 | 0]
08:25:26.872 [+] [T:000FE8] [S:1:1:1124:5607:5] LANMSGTYPESTOPPED [0/2 | 0]
08:25:28.084 [+] [T:000F1C] [O:TASK] <<< Processing: 0
08:25:29.526 [+] [T:000FEC] [S:1:1:1124:5607:5] LANMSGTYPESTARTED [0/2 | 0]
08:25:31.101 [+] [T:000F1C] [O:TASK] <<< Processing: 0
08:25:34.119 [+] [T:000F1C] [O:TASK] <<< Processing: 0
08:25:34.600 [D] [T:000FF8] [F:LANTALK2C] <CMD>LANMSG</CMD>
<MBXID>1162</MBXID><MBXTO>5607</MBXTO><SUBTEXT>LanTalk</SUBTEXT><MOBILEADDR>
</MOBILEADDR><LAP>0</LAP><SMS>0</SMS><MSGTEXT>i have no clue whats going 
on</MSGTEXT>
08:25:34.610 [+] [T:000FF8] [S:1:1:1162:5760:5] LANMSG [15/2 | 0]
08:25:34.800 [+] [T:000FF0] [S:1:1:1162:5760:5] LANMSGTYPESTOPPED [0/2 | 0]
```

And here is what my output format should look like:

```
8:25:00 AM [John Smith] to [Steve Jobs] but didn't give me the info I needed
8:25:00 AM [John Smith] to [Steve Jobs] i have no clue whats going on
```

I need the code to sort through the lines of code, select only lines that contain LANTALK, apply the formatting and output chronologically, while discarding all other lines along the way. I have no idea how to do this. Any help you could give me would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a specific problem? Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service.

Comment: some effort from you part goes along way.

Comment: I've been at this for 4 hours. I just need a direction to go in.

Comment: You description of the problem is pretty accurate. Take a break to clear up your head. BTW previous comment "a long" is the correct spelling

Comment: Message can be parsed by using XML parser to get value inside `<MSGTEXT>` on the string after `[F:LANTALK2C]` in your code. For the time part, just convert the time to nearest minute for the first string read before the whitespace.